# Compiling OLEDB dependent executables on x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linker, oledb, x86-64

I compiled my executable that used the Access Database Engine libraries on Windows XP 32bit.
Running that on the Win7 x64 OS gave me an error that the OLEDB components were not registered.

I tried to install the AccessDatabaseEngine x64 and it fixed the problem.
However on another machine with Win7 x64 and office 2007 32bit installed, it wouldn't let me install the AccessDatabaseEngine x64 and so I was left to compile the project on that target machine (in VS2010 c#) with the Env as x64 and target CPU as x86. This fixed the problem.

My question is, why does this work? What's the reasoning behind this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer your question what you are stating means that there for one is a different OS but should not matter.. the real issue here is that there are 2 different versions of Microsoft Installed.. you would have to either

1. GAC the version or Reference the version of the Target Machine
2. Set Copy Local of the .DLL in the working version to the Target version.. sort of like where your DLL's would reside in the Debug/Bin or Debug/Release folder where the bin folder resides..

I am working on Windows 7 64 bit and copied my working dll's over to a Windows 2003 server machine and my projects still work..

my other work around was to reference the Microsoft.Interop.Access .dll's from the Target machine into my Solution, recompile and Bam....!